# Pegar resultado de busca no google com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google

Olá, estou querendo saber uma forma de fazer o seguinte:
Utilizando JQuery, quero pegar o link do 1° resultado de uma busca no Google.

Um exemplo:

```
$("#bt_tempInfo").load("https://www.google.com.br/search?q=exemplo ._Rm:first-child", function(){
            link = "http://"+$("#bt_tempInfo").text();
        });
```

Só que não tenho permissão para fazer em outra página(claro).
Então gostaria de saber, uma forma de fazer isso...Existe alguma extensão que posso utilizar do Google, ou algo semelhante?

Comment: O Google [tem uma API para isso](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).

Comment: Hmm, acho que assim não dá certo. Teria alguma outra forma?

Answer (score 1):

Usando somente jQuery não sei se tem como... porém creio que dá pra fazer em PHP.

```
<?php
 // Endereço do site
 $url = 'http://www.site.com.br';

 // Pegando dados do Site e colocando em uma String
 $dadosSite = file_get_contents($url);

 // Exibindo o retorno
 echo $dadosSite;
?>
```

No caso se adaptar, acho que conseguirá fazer o que deseja.

Referências:

http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/php/como-pegar-parte-do-conteudo-dados-de-outro-site-com-php/

http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/pegar-conteudo-de-outro-site-com-php

Answer (score 1):

Como você não pode utilizar a `Google Custom Search` como sugerido pelo `Sergio`, você pode arriscar o `Google Web Search API`, mas lembre-se que este está `deprecated` desde Novembro de 2010.

Neste caso, você pode carregar a API na sua pagina, ocultar o elemento com a pesquisa, setar o texto a ser pesquisado e esperar o retorno.

No exemplo abaixo, eu montei um Objeto que carrega `Google Web Search API`, ele dispara um evento (`onInitComplte`) quando o `Search` estiver disponível e outro evento (`onSearchComplete`) quando a consulta está completa.

No exemplo abaixo, ele loga no console o link patrocionado e o primeiro link.

```js
var Busca = function (element) {
  this.container = element;
  this.initialize();
}

Busca.prototype.buscar = function (texto) {
  var self = this;
  var click = new Event("click");
  
  self.control.prefillQuery(texto);
  //self.input.value = texto;
  self.button.dispatchEvent(click);
}

Busca.prototype.initialize = function () {
  var self = this;
  google.load("search", "1");  
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {  
    var search = {};
    self.control = new google.search.SearchControl();
    self.control.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());
    self.control.addSearcher(new google.search.NewsSearch());
    self.control.draw(self.container);
    self.input = self.container.querySelector("input.gsc-input");
    self.button = self.container.querySelector("input.gsc-search-button");
    self.result = self.container.querySelector("div.gsc-results-wrapper-nooverlay");
    
    self.control.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, function (event) {
      console.log(event);
      var results = {};
      results.container = self.result.querySelector("div.gsc-results");
      results.primeiro = {};
      results.primeiro.container = results.container.querySelector("div.gsc-result");
      results.primeiro.titulo = results.primeiro.container.querySelector("a.gs-title");

      var expansao = {};

      expansao = {};
      expansao.container = results.container.querySelector("div.gsc-expansionArea");
      expansao.primeiro = {};
      expansao.primeiro.container = expansao.container.querySelector("div.gsc-result");
      expansao.primeiro.titulo = expansao.primeiro.container.querySelector("a.gs-title");
      
      results.expansao = expansao;
      if (self.onSearchComplete) {
        self.onSearchComplete(event.hf, results);
      }
    });
    self.onInitComplete();
  });
}

var container = document.getElementById("searchcontrol");
var search = new Busca(container);
search.onInitComplete = function () {
  search.buscar("Hello Wolrd");
}
search.onSearchComplete = function (texto, results) {
  console.log([
    texto, 
    results.primeiro.titulo.href, 
    results.expansao.primeiro.titulo.href
  ]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="searchcontrol"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigão, tenta com ajax

```
function googleSearch(settings){

    var apiURL = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0';

    $.getJSON(apiURL,{
        q   : 'boschini busca',
    },function(r){
        console.info('Data:',r);
    });
}

googleSearch()
```